# A* Heuristic Search fails to find the target node

Tags: artificial-intelligence, a-star, heuristics

**Consider this graph:**
[image: Problem Graph]

We define S a the starting node and G as the target node.
A* should find G, because it always finds the target.

But implementing A* based on the lowest f(n) where f(n) = g(n) + h(n) leads to this path:
S -> B -> X or Y

X & Y heuristic is zero (thus they got to be target nodes) but our real target, as far as the definition of the problem is concerned, is G.
**Does that mean that the heuristic we choose is not admissible?**

Comment: The algorithm should still go on since it didn’t find the target, unless the target is assumed to be any node with zero value.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen But isn't, h(n) = 0 <=> n is a target, a prerequisite for A* Algorithm?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. It’s just a bad heuristics function, but my implementations know which node they want to get to and stop there, not based on heuristics. Heuristics only guides the search process